# Update real time data instantly and constantly from server on android client using Volley

Tags: android, synchronization, android-volley, auto-update

I'm new to android programming.
I want to use Volley library to manage communication of my server and client. But I'm confused with syncing mechanism I should use.

I want to reflect my database values changes to my android clients every second ( I suppose my values in database updates every second!).

Does volley manage to do this iteration or should I use another Iteration mechanism to compel Volley to get data from server constantly?

Is Volley enough for this purpose or should I use it with something like SyncAdapter? 
If I should use Sync Adapter for repeating volley requests to reflect my data updates , How to do this efficiently?
Thanks in advance for your valuable answers!